# $_POST dosen't work in page called by AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I Have a problem. I try to `$_POST` my form, but i dosen't work in part of code(subpage.php) called by AJAX. I tried to make $_POST on main page and it's work perfect, but on subpage it dosent't work

This way I call sub page with data:

```
$("place_item").on("click", function(){
$("#company_place_item_section").show('slide', {direction : 'left'}, 500);
var place_click_id = $(this).attr('place_id');

$.post
 (
    'http://site.ru/section/subpage.php',
    {
        place_clicked_id:place_click_id
    },
    function(data){
        $("#place_item_section").html(data);
    }
 );
});
```

This is the code that does not work in the subpage but it works on the main:

```
if(isset($_POST['send-file-button']))
            {
                if ($_FILES)
                {
                    $upload_filename = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
                    $filename_explode = substr($upload_filename, strrpos($upload_filename, '.'));
                    $new_upload_filename = 'img_'.$add_showcase_img.$filename_explode;
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'],'../data/'.'places/'.'$place_item'.'/'.$new_upload_filename);
                }

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO showcase (place_id, showcase_img) VALUES ('$place_item','$new_upload_filename')");
            }
```

HTML part of code:

```
<form method="post" name="place_showcase" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="filename" class="load_showcase_img" showcase_img_id="<?php echo $add_showcase_img; ?>"/>
    <input name="send-file-button" type="submit" value="save image"/>
</form>
```

Help me please. What could be the problem and how it can be solved? It may be necessary to call `$_POST` globally. For example after load page by AJAX JQUERY .CLICK doesn't work, but .ON or .DELEGATE work great!

Comment: Perhaps I'm being stupid, but it doesn't look to me as if you are actually sending a file... You aren't even sending a `send-file` parameter.

Comment: Please explain what you actually mean by "doesn't work"...""

Comment: and where's the HTML form for this?

Comment: Edit my question, and put HTML part of code

Comment: You send to php-script one parameter `place_clicked_id`. Why do you think that `isset($_POST['send-file-button'])` is __true__?

Comment: Dosen't work - It's mean that: when I try to post thisit dosen't work and only reload the page without any action, but when i put it into begining of the page or in new clear page for testing - it's work! Problem in $_POST

Comment: 'place_clicked_id' it's value which I use futher in my scripts like $place_item = $_POST['place_clicked_id'];

Answer (score 0):

To your jQuery problem, try use:

```
$(document).on("place_item", "click", function() {
```

Could you give more details about the subpage?

Comment: My problem in PHP, may be in AJAX